# Global variable isn't global or doesn't contain the value I expected it to contain?

Tags: delphi

I've got the following code in Form1.

```
public
  { Public declarations }
  cas: integer;
end;
```

Then I work with the variable, and then I call another form with `Form2.ShowModal;` On Form2 I try to execute the following: `Label9.Caption:=Format('%ds',[Form1.cas]);`. But no matter what I do, in Form1 'cas' is assigned the proper value but in Form2 it always shows "0s". Why does that happen?

EDIT:

Now I have in the first unit called 'kolecka' this

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  barvy: array[1..6] of TColor;
  kola: array[1..22] of TShape;
  valid: integer;
  bezi: boolean;
  presnost: real;
  skore: integer;
  chyb: integer;
  kliku: integer;
  cas: integer;
```

and this in the other unit called 'dialog':

```
implementation

uses
  kolecka;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure Statistiky();
begin
  With Form2 do begin
    Label8.Caption:=IntToStr(kolecka.skore);
    Label9.Caption:=Format('%ds',[kolecka.cas]);
    Label10.Caption:=IntToStr(kolecka.cas);
    Label11.Caption:=IntToStr(skore);
    Label12.Caption:=Format('%.2f%%',[presnost]);
  end;
end;
```

But it still doesn't work.. still shows a zero.

EDIT2:

I feel like every answer says something different and I'm very confused..

EDIT3: This is how 'cas' is manipulated in Form1

```
procedure TForm1.Timer3Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  cas:=cas+1;
  Form1.Label5.Caption:=IntToStr(cas);
end;
```

FOUND IT!

Meh. I figured out where was the problem.
I was assigning the label captions on Form2 Create and not Show, so of course they were at 0 >.>

Comment: Where/when is `Form1.cas` assigned the value you expect to see from `Form2`?

Comment: It's extremely cheesy to do things in `FormCreate` other than to create objects that belong to the form, which you then free in `FormDestroy`. Don't put "app logic" that assumes other objects outside that form even exist yet, in `FormCreate` ever!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original question, you declared a field in an object, and you thought it was a global, perhaps?

```
unit unit1;

interface 

uses Stuff;

type 
 TForm1 = class(TForm)
   public
     THisIsAFieldInAnObject:Integer;
 end

var
  ThisIsAGlobal:Integer;

implementation

uses OtherStuff;

...
```

Notice where you put globals above. Global variables are not fields inside a class. Where you put something, when you write code is called "the context you are in". Inside a class declaration, something like `public` makes sense as a visiblity specifier. It does not make things global, it makes them visible to users of the class.

To access the global, access it as unitName.VariableName, and don't forget to add 'Uses unitName' to the other unit.

**Update** You are now correctly accessing the global variable, and it doesn't contain the value you expected. That's where we start debugging. Set a breakpoint on the place where you set the variable, and on any other place where it is changed back to 0. Now set a breakpoint on the place where you read the variable.  I find that variable writes work better when they actually happen, and when they aren't over-written by a subsequent write to the same place, that contains a different value.  Variables are like a box which contains a number. Zero things writing to it (the code you thought got called did not get called) or two things writing to it (the thing you think should be there but is not there because the second write zapped the first value)  are common sources of your sort of confusion.

Comment: This is what I have in the edited post but still doesn't work

Comment: Say Hello my friend, to the Debugger.

Comment: Well. Right before I call Form2 I printed 'cas' and it showed the correct value. So the problem is in Form2 or in the calling of it?

Comment: Or that you have more than one place where you declare cas, so the name cas means something different in the one place than in the other.  When you increment cas in the form, for example, you might be incrementing a local field named cas.  Change it to "Inc(kolecka.cas)".

Comment: with Inc it doesn't compile :/

Comment: Okay kolecak.cas := kolecka.cas + 1 (to avoid using self.cas).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10020/discussion-between-warren-p-and-argoneus)

Answer (score 1):

You have a global variable: `kolecka.cas` and a field `kolecka.Form1.cas`. Those are different.

```
public
  { Public declarations }
  cas: integer;//This is the field
end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  cas: integer;//This is the global variable
```

`Label9.Caption:=Format('%ds',[kolecka.cas]);` accesses the global variable.

`cas` in an instance method of `TForm1` refers to the field.

Comment: I don't see what you mean >.>

Comment: You have two different `cas`es, so it shouldn't be surprising they're different.

Comment: It's hard to explain lexical scoping to someone who can't perceive it.

Answer (score 1):

On `Label10.Caption:=IntToStr(kolecka.cas);`, you're actually reading the `cas` global variable of unit `kolecka`, not the `Form1`'s one.

In the first case, you could be trying to manipulate`Form1.cas` after call `Form2.ShowModal`. Please take note that, code following a ShowModal call won't be executed until you close the form shown with `ShowModal`.

**UPDATE**
It seems you're manipulating unit's `cas` variable, not form's one. I exactly do not know how Delphi treats this case. But it a good practice to explicity indicate which `cas` instance you are manipulating. Use this code:

```
self.cas := self.cas + 1;
```

Comment: I manipulate 'cas' before and even print it before calling Form2 :/

Comment: @argoneus, please show us how you manipulate ``cas`` varible.

Comment: You have to put ``self.cas := self.cas + 1;`` in OnTimer event inside your form's code. Self is a reference to the current instance of TForm1.

Comment: The "undeclared variable" error is imposible is you write your code like this http://pastebin.com/6AeN6KYh

Comment: I copypasted it, and got `[Error] kolecka.pas(254): Undeclared identifier: 'cas'`

Comment: That's means TForm1 class don't has a ``cas`` variable/property.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would check is if you have only 1 variable named Form1.

My best guess would be that you have 1 in unit `Unit1`(Where TForm1 is declared) and 1 in unit `Kolecka`, but that's just an assumption.